# Avoid `fetch()` marking model attributes as changed

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm using Backbone in a user settings profile form. I fetch the model and render its information into the form. When I save the model *all* the parameters are sent instead of the ones changed by the user.

First I fetch the mode and render it on the view:

```
// Fetch model and render on view
user = new User({ id: 123 });
user.fetch().done(function () {
    view.render();
});
```

When the user changes a field I updated the model with the 'set()' method:

```
"change .email": function () {
    this.model.set("email", this.email.val());
}
```

Later in the view code I save on a click event (using `patch: true`):

```
"click .save": function () {
    console.log(this.model.changedAttributes());  // Shows all the model attributes
    this.model.save({ patch: true }); // Sends all the model attributes
 }
```

How can I avoid Backbone marking as changed after the `fetch` I use to initialize the model?

Comment: Can you please show how you update your model?

Comment: @VitaliyPetrychuk I don't it's relevant but I included it anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This hack will solve your problem:

```
model.fetch({context:model}).done(function () {
  this.set({});
  view.render();
});
```

Comment: @eliocs because here https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L322 `changed` property sets to `{}`. Because `attrs === {}` we skip this loop https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L331