# backbone.stickit and html-form: How to save (patch) only changed attributes?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-model, backbone-stickit, http-patch

**tl;dr**

How to use backbone.stickit with a html form to change an existing model fetched from the server and only PATCH the changed attributes (changed by user input within the html form) to the server?

**/tl;dr**

I'm using [backbone.stickit](https://github.com/NYTimes/backbone.stickit) in a backbone.js application to bind a model to a HTML-form which is part of a backbone view. This works fine so far, but it becomes a little bit complicated if I'm going to save the bound model. This is because I want to use the PATCH-method and only send the changed attributes to the server. I try to illustrate what I've done so far:

**Fetching the model from Server**

```
user = new User(); //instatiate a new user-model
user.fetch(); //fetching the model from the server

console.log(user.changedAttributes()); // Returns ALL attributes, because model was empty
```

The last line indicates my problem, because I thought I can used the `changedAtrributes()` method later to get the attributes which need a patch on the server. So I tried this workaround which I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14485366/avoid-fetch-marking-model-attributes-as-changed)

```
user.fetch({
    success: function (model, response, options) {
        model.set({});
    }
});

user.changedAtrributes(); //Returns now "false"
```

**Do stickit-bindings**

Now I render my view and call the `stickit()` method on the view, to do the bindings:

```
//Bindings specified in the view:
[...]
bindings: {
  "#username" : "username"
  "#age"      : "age"
}

[...]

//within the render method of the view
this.stickit();
```

The bindings work fine and my user model gets updated, but `changedAttributes()` remain empty all the time.

**Save the model to the server**

If the user has made all required changes, the model should be saved to the server. I want to use the PATCH method and only send the changed attributes to the server.

```
user.save(null, {patch:true}); //PATCH method is used but ALL attributes are sent to the server
```

OR

```
user.save(user.changedAttributes(),{patch : true});
```

With the second approach there are different outcomes:

1. if I didn't use the `user.set({})` woraround, all attributes get PATCHED to the server
2. if I use the `user.set({})` woraround the return value of `changedAttributes()` is "false" and all attributes are PUT to the server
3. if I call a `user.set("age","123")` before calling `save()`, then only the age attribute is PATCHED to the server

So outcome 3 is my desired behaviour, but there are 2 problems with this: First stickit doesn't seem to use the `set()` method on the model to update the attributes if they are changed within the html-form. And second, if you call `set()` with one attribute and afterwards with another, only the second attributes is returned by `changedAttributes()`.

Maybe I just overseen something in the backbone or backbone.stickit docs, so I didn't get the desired behaviour working. Any ideas about that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**NOTE:** As found out the problem wasn't directly related to backbone.stickit, more to backbone itself.

Solved this problem on my own, maybe this helps someone who may stumble upon this question:

Backbone only keep track of *unchanged* attributes, but not of *unsaved* attributes. So with

```
model.changedAttributes();
```

you will only get the attributes of the model, which was changed since the last

```
model.set("some_attribute","some_value")
```

Finally I stumbled upon [backbone.trackit](https://github.com/NYTimes/backbone.trackit) which is a backbone.js plugin maintained by the creator of backbone.stickit. With this plugin you can track *unsaved* attributes (all attributes which have changed since the last `model.save()`) and then use them in the save-method of a model. Example (my usecase):

```
Backbone.View.extend({
  bindings: {
    "#name" : "name",
    "#age"  : "age"
  },

  initialize: function () {
    this.model = new User();
    this.model.fetch({
      success: function (model, response, options) {
        //this tells backbone.stickit to track unsaved attributes
        model.startTracking(); 
      }
    });
  },

  render: function () {
    this.$el.html(tmpl);
    this.stickit();
    return this;
  },

  onSaveUserToServer: function () {
    //first argument: only unsaved attributes, second argument: tell backbone to PATCH
    this.model.save(this.model.unsavedAttributes(), { patch: true });
  });

});
```